# I have this assignment for my vb.net course. Whats wrong?

Tags: vb.net

OK so the assignment is

```
1) Write a program using various procedures to perform the operations listed below. Call these procedures using delegates. Make sure to document your program and have the program print descriptive text along with the numbers in b. and c.
    a) Print a text string in reverse word order. 
    b) Print the number of characters in the string.
    c) Print number of words in the string.
```

I have tried the following code but I get a exception with the AllGreets.DynamicInvoke. What do I do to fix this?

I am not much of a programmer and taking this class wasn't the best choice I ever made but now I have to finish it. As it was already paid for.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim part1 As GreetingDelegate
        Dim part2 As GreetingDelegate
        Dim part3 As GreetingDelegate
        Dim part4 As GreetingDelegate

        part1 = AddressOf greating
        part2 = AddressOf greatingchar
        part3 = AddressOf reverse
        part4 = AddressOf number

        Dim AllGreets As GreetingDelegate = _
                      [Delegate].Combine(part1, part2, part3, part4)

        AllGreets.DynamicInvoke()
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Sub GreetingDelegate(ByVal MsgString As String)

    ' What the greating is
    Public Sub greating()

        Console.WriteLine("The greating is Hi how are you?")
        System.Console.WriteLine("press enter")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    ' Number of char in string
    Public Sub greatingchar()

        Dim thing As Long
        thing = Len("Hi how are you?")
        System.Console.WriteLine("There is")
        System.Console.WriteLine(thing)
        System.Console.WriteLine("characters in this greating")
        System.Console.WriteLine("press enter")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub reverse()

        ' string in reverse
        Dim t As String

        t = StrReverse$("Visual Basic")

        System.Console.WriteLine(t)
        System.Console.WriteLine("press enter")
        System.Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Sub number()

        'number of word in string

        Dim count As Long
        Dim text As String

        text = "Hi how are you?"
        count = text.Split(" ").Length
        System.Console.WriteLine(count)
        System.Console.WriteLine("press enter")
        System.Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: The method must match the delegate declaration.  Clearly that's not the case, greating() doesn't take a string argument.  And you forget to pass a string to the DynamicInvoke() method.

Comment: Just get rid of the underscore and equal sign in the line above and put quotation marks with a space in the invoke parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A delegate defines the signature that implementers must use. In your case, you defined a method that takes a string as input parameter and returned nothing. In order to use that, your implementing methods must agree with that signature. For example, a greeting method (BTW, spell your methods correctly), would need to be as follows if you want it to behave like a GreetingDelegate:

```
Public Sub Greeting(msgString As String)
   ' Do something with msgString
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if you don't need the input string, your delegate could be declared as follows, but realize that all methods that you are defining of this delegate type would also not allow input string parameters either (because they wouldn't agree with the declared signatures).

```
Public Delegate Sub GreetingDelegate()
```